# TextView doesn't wrap text

Tags: android, text, textview, word-wrap, android-wrap-content

I need dynamically create next xml:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:text="a lot of text will be here"
            />
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
```

and here is my code:

```
LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
        ll.setLayoutParams(layoutLP);

        TextView title = new TextView(getActivity());
        title.setText("a lot of text will be here");
        title.setLayoutParams(textLP);

        EditText editText = new EditText(getActivity());
        editText.setLayoutParams(ediLP);
        editText.setSingleLine();

        ll.addView(title);
        ll.addView(editText);
```

```
layoutLP = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        layoutLP.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;

textLP = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        textLP.weight = 2;
        textLP.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;

editLP = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        editLP.weight = 3;
        editLP.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
```

However, on device I get problem: `text` inside `textView` is not wrapped and partly covered by `editText`.

Why does this happen?

[image]

And here is how it must looks like:

[image]

Comment: Post screen shot here

Comment: try the layoutParams with: LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 3f); or similar for every view, maybe this works better

Comment: @Opiatefuchs, nope, that doesn't help (

Comment: ok, to get a clear idea what exactly is not working, please post a screenshot of Your result if possible (and maybe how it should be)

Comment: @SuhasB, please, see updates

Comment: @Opiatefuchs, i am add also a scree how it must looks like. please see updates

Comment: please check this answer is it working ? http://stackoverflow.com/a/35223523/2826147 @StanMalcolm

Comment: @AmitVaghela, please read question one more time!
i need create this layout dynamically , without xml

Comment: in Your images it seems that both views should be equal width, or? If You set every weight to 1, does this work? Sorry for just trying something, but there are often differences by adding views programmatically instead of in xml layout...

Comment: So maybe this is a default behaviour of programmatically added views. Set the singleLine attribute to false after setting Your layoutParams to the textview: textLP.setSingleLine(false);

Comment: @Opiatefuchs, nope (
setSingleLine(false) - doesn't help to

screenshot are different, cos make it on different diveces

Comment: ah, that´s important to know if You test it on different devices. So, doesn´t it work on all devices or only on some devices....

Comment: @StanMalcolm I have added answer with some demo code with screen shot.

Comment: The only thing I can imagine now is, first set the layoutParams to Your views and at the end set text and add the views to the linear layout. maybe it is an order problem when You add the attributes...

Comment: I found the reason, if you interested - please see UPDATE 2...
thanks again and sorry for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your Activity should be**

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutLP = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        layoutLP.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
        layoutLP.weight = 2;

        LinearLayout linearLayout1 = new LinearLayout(this);
        linearLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutLP);
        linearLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutLP);
        linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams textLP = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        textLP.weight = 2;
        textLP.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams editLP = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        editLP.weight = 3;
        editLP.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;


        // Add textview 1
        TextView textView1 = new TextView(this);
        textView1.setLayoutParams(textLP);
        textView1.setText("programmatically created TextView1");
//        textView1.setBackgroundColor(0xff66ff66); // hex color 0xAARRGGBB
        textView1.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);// in pixels (left, top, right, bottom)
        linearLayout1.addView(textView1);

        // Add textview 1
        EditText editText = new EditText(this);
        editText.setLayoutParams(editLP);
        editText.setHint("programmatically created TextView1");
//        editText.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY); // hex color 0xAARRGGBB
        editText.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);// in pixels (left, top, right, bottom)
        linearLayout1.addView(editText);
        linearLayout.addView(linearLayout1);
```

**Your xml file should be:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/ll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image: Here Screen Shot]

Comment: this is looks like some king of magic...
there is no big difference between your and mine code...
but after some refactoring it works now...
thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Try your phone or a phone with similar dpi-resolution properties as yours on the AVD, see if it is the same problem. Maybe the resolution on your phone is the problem.